# How can I pull different items from an array within a class?

Tags: swift

I'm creating a quiz application with multiple categories. If the user would like to select a category, they would "turn on" the switch for that category. Then a Bool value will be set to true if the switch is on and false if it is off. This Bool value would then be sent to the next view controller where if it had a true value, a function would run that would add the array of the selected category's question, to an array that holds the arrays of the selected categories.

Currently, this is how my application functions: 
I have a swift file called Question, which creates a class for the basic structure of a question. Then I have another file called QuestionBank which holds a class, and within that class is an array of the questions I created using the class within the Question.swift file. From there, in the view controller for my game, I call the class that holds the array of questions and my code then displays each question, with all its options, in the order that they were called in the array. How would I make it so that the users can access specific questions or a specific group of questions within the array based on user input? I already attempted creating multiple arrays of questions and attempting to call those and combine so the user can be tested on both categories, but I am unable to for some reason.

First View Controller:

```
import UIKit


class ViewControllerTrivia: UIViewController {
    var historySelection = Bool()

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let gameController = segue.destination as! ViewControllerGame
    gameController.isHistorySelected = historySelection
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @IBAction func swipeToHome(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "triviaToHome", sender: ViewControllerHome.self)}

    @IBAction func startGame(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "triviaToGame", sender: ViewControllerGame.self)
    }

    @IBAction func historySelectionSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if (sender.isOn == true) {
            var historySelection = true
            print("on")
        } else {
            var historySelection = false
            print("off")
        }

    }
}

Second View Controller:

import UIKit



class ViewControllerGame: UIViewController {
    var isHistorySelected = Bool()
    @IBOutlet weak var questionCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    //Outlet for Buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var optionA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionD: UIButton!

    var allQuestions = [(Question(questionText: "History: What does FBLA stand for?", choiceA: "A. Formidable Business Learners of America", choiceB: "B. Future Business Learners of America", choiceC: "C.Future Business Leaders of America", choiceD: "D.Fleeting Business Learners Of America", answer: 3)),]
    var historyQuestions = [(Question(questionText: "History: Who was the founder of the FBLA program?", choiceA: "A. Edward D. Miller", choiceB: "B. Conrad N. Hilton", choiceC: "C. Hamden L. Forkner", choiceD: "Elena Daly", answer: 3)) ]

    var questionNumber: Int = 0
    var score: Int = 0
    var selectedAnswer: Int = 0

    func questionSelection() {
        if isHistorySelected == true{
            allQuestions.append(contentsOf: historyQuestions)
        }
    }

    //Making only the top corners of the progress view visible
    func roundProgressCorners() {
    self.progressView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        roundProgressCorners()
        questionSelection()
        updateQuestion()
        updateUI()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == selectedAnswer{
            print("correct")
            score += 1
        }else {
            print("wrong")
        }
        questionNumber += 1
        updateQuestion()

    }
    func updateQuestion(){

        if questionNumber <= allQuestions.count - 1{
            questionLabel.text = allQuestions[questionNumber].question
            optionA.setTitle(allQuestions[questionNumber].optionA, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            optionB.setTitle(allQuestions[questionNumber].optionB, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            optionC.setTitle(allQuestions[questionNumber].optionC, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            optionD.setTitle(allQuestions[questionNumber].optionD, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            selectedAnswer = allQuestions[questionNumber].correctAnswer
            updateUI()

        }else {
            restartQuiz()
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameToEndScreen", sender: ViewControllerEndScreen.self)
        }


    }
    func updateUI(){
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        questionCounter.text = "\(questionNumber + 1)/\(allQuestions.count)"
        progressView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / CGFloat(allQuestions.count)) * CGFloat(questionNumber + 1)

    }
    func restartQuiz(){
        score = 0
        questionNumber = 0
        updateQuestion()

    }


}
```

For the final result, I would prefer for the user to be able to select which categories they would like to be quizzed on and then the app will then combine the selected categories.

Comment: can you update with question class, u want to filter questions according to categor..?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to re-design your data structure, I though of something as below, may be helpful to you or you can get some more idea.

```
//1. Create an enum of Question Category
enum QuestionCatgory: String{
    case Sports = "Sports"
    case Politics = "Politicd"
    case Science = "Science"
}

//2. Create a Structure that will hold details about each Question, including its category
struct QuestionsDetail{
    let question: String
    let options: [String]
    let currectOption: Int
    let category: QuestionCatgory

    init(question: String, options: [String], correctOption: Int, category: QuestionCatgory){
        self.question = question
        self.options = options
        self.currectOption = correctOption
        self.category = category
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var questionList: [QuestionsDetail] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //3. Create data source of your question. Preferably get this data from backend or store it in a Plist or JSON file for better maintainability. In this example its hardcoded
        questionList = createDataSource()

        //4. Call this method to get questions specific for a Category. You can use this array to populate the question in a ViewController. Use delegate to capture user response to maintain the scorecard and other things
        let questionListOfCategory = getQuestionsList(forCategory: .Science)

        print("Questions List for:\n\(questionListOfCategory)\n")

    }

    func getQuestionsList(forCategory category: QuestionCatgory) -> [QuestionsDetail]{

        var questionListOfCategory: [QuestionsDetail] = []

        for question in questionList {
            if question.category.rawValue == category.rawValue{
                questionListOfCategory.append(question)
            }
        }

        return questionListOfCategory
    }

    func createDataSource() -> [QuestionsDetail]{
        let questionDetail1 = QuestionsDetail(question: "Question1", options: ["Option1 A", "Option1 B", "Option1 C", "Option1 D"], correctOption: 2, category: .Sports)
        let questionDetail2 = QuestionsDetail(question: "Question2", options: ["Option2 A", "Option2 B", "Option2 C", "Option2 D"], correctOption: 4, category: .Politics)
        let questionDetail3 = QuestionsDetail(question: "Question3", options: ["Option3 A", "Option3 B", "Option3 C", "Option3 D"], correctOption: 1, category: .Science)
        let questionDetail4 = QuestionsDetail(question: "Question4", options: ["Option4 A", "Option4 B", "Option4 C", "Option4 D"], correctOption: 3, category: .Sports)
        let questionDetail5 = QuestionsDetail(question: "Question5", options: ["Option5 A", "Option5 B", "Option5 C", "Option5 D"], correctOption: 4, category: .Politics)

        var questionList: [QuestionsDetail] = []

        questionList.append(questionDetail1)
        questionList.append(questionDetail2)
        questionList.append(questionDetail3)
        questionList.append(questionDetail4)
        questionList.append(questionDetail5)

        return questionList
    }


}
```